# Magento 2 firstname, lastname, vat_id custom validation

Tags: magento2, checkout, validation

I want to change the validation of firstname, lastname and vat_id in checkout. I've already changed the telephone validation by changing validation item in checkout_index_index.xml like so:

```
<item name="telephone" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="phoneCustom" xsi:type="string">true</item>
    </item>
</item>
```

The problem is that I cannot find where firstname, lastname and vat_id declarations are. In which xml should I look?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that I've only had to add additional items to the checkout_index_index.xml file. Eg:

```
<item name="firstname" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="my-custom-validation" xsi:type="string">true</item>
        <item name="letters-only" xsi:type="string">true</item>
    </item>
</item>
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstname, lastname and vat_id are attributes, So check **Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor::process**, this process method generate actual array of input field. If you need extra validation then create your own by xml.